# HexToString function returning maximum of 16kb

Tags: c#

The `HexToString` function returning maximum of 16kb even for sources greater than 16KB

```
string HexStringToString(string HexString)
        {
            string stringValue = "";
            for (int i = 2; i < HexString.Length / 2; i++) // Starting from position too just to avoid the 0x Hex Code that messes stuff up
            {
                try
                {
                    string hexChar = HexString.Substring(i * 2, 2);
                    int hexValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexChar, 16);
                    stringValue += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(hexValue);
                }
                catch (Exception ExCon)
                {
                    //continue; //Forcing application to ignore anomaly in the file being processed
                    MessageBox.Show(ExCon.ToString());
                }
            }
            return stringValue;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. You may want to edit a bit more information about your code, into your post. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Phrancis.. Was my first post.. Will readthe link to improve my posts.. Thank U

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` instead of `string` for the `stringValue` variable. `+= ...` becomes `.Append(...)` and `return stringValue` becomes `return stringValue.ToString()`

Comment: Thanks Jeese. I see what you mean. Just did that with this routine:       private string HexString2Ascii(string hexString)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 2; i <= hexString.Length - 2; i += 2)
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(hexString.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }  // Still dont know how to format and paste code here yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a few comments.

First, I'd change the loop a bit. Instead of:

```
for (int i = 2; i < HexString.Length / 2; i++)
// ...
     HexString.Substring(i * 2, 2);
```

I'd use something like:

```
for (int i=2; i<HexString.Length-1; i += 2)
// ...
    HexString.Substring(i, 2);
```

Note the `Length - 1` though--if we happen to be passed a string with odd length, we don't want to index beyond its end.

Secondly, at least for general use, you almost certainly do *not* want this to catch the exception and display a MessageBox. The basic reason for using exception handling to start with is that a low-level function like this doesn't know (and shouldn't care) how such an exception will be handled/displayed, whether to continue execution after it happens, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I incorporated you suggestions into the code now but still gets max of 16KB for converted output files :(

Comment: @Wilhelmn: Yes, that's pretty much expected: the basic idea here is that we help with refactoring code to make it cleaner, but the primary intent isn't fixing bugs. Questions about getting the code to produce different results mostly belong on [SO].

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Heading over there now..